# detect new subscription and call backend

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I need to be able to call a method in my backend after a developer creates an account in the APIM dev portal. Is there a way to achieve that?
I've seen in the documentation in advanced policy that I could send a one way request. So can I detect a new sub and make those 2 work together or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get proactively notified of user registration and subscription creation is delegation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-setup-delegation